# How can I disable the rest position programmatically?

Tags: animation, armature, bones, pose-mode

I am currently trying to write a custom importer for the model format used in Ocarina of Time 3D, but I've reached a bottleneck in regards to how Blender stores models internally.

In OoT3D, models are stored as a skeleton, with bones at rest positions/rotations relative to their parent bone. In each animation, it specifies new positions/rotations for each bone that are meant to overwrite the rest pose.

However, in Blender, it looks like the rest pose is always active. Any animations that you define are *added* on top of the rest pose, rather than replacing it.

This introduces bugs into animations, such as:

### Incorrect Rotations

---

Since the rest and animation rotations are added together, at first I tried naively using `(animation rotation - rest rotation)`. However, no matter what I did this didn't work.

It turns out this is because they aren't merged together as `ZᵣZₐ * YᵣYₐ * XᵣXₐ`, but rather `ZᵣYᵣXᵣ * ZₐYₐXₐ`. Because the rotations are applied by rest/animation rather than axis, it would accumulate error over the second set of axes.

I found it was necessary to switch to quaternions, by calculating the inverse to counteract the first `ZᵣYᵣXᵣ`. So it's effectively `ZᵣYᵣXᵣ * inverse(ZᵣYᵣXᵣ) * ZₐYₐXₐ`. This works visually, but requires a keyframe at every index in the animation. This would make it really tedious to edit any of these animations.

---

### Incorrect Translations

---

I'm currently having trouble adding animations on top of the rotation approach. Again, I tried the naive approach of `(animation position - rest position)`. This was close, but this didn't work either.

This seems to again be due to how transformations are applied in Blender. It looks like transforms are roughly calculated as: `mat(translationᵣ) * mat(rotationᵣ) * mat(translationₐ) * mat(rotationₐ)`. Like above, since the translations are separated, that rotation in between introduces some error when the second translation is finally applied.

There might be some way to calculate new positions based on the rest position/rotation, but this sounds complicated for what should be a straightforward problem.

---

I've been trying to find documentation on this issue, but I can't seem to find it addressed anywhere online. I've been thinking of trying the following approaches to fix it:

- It looks like PoseBones have a number of constraints you can add that change how the final transformation is calculated. It seems plausible that there would be a constraint that could disable the rest pose from being considered in the final calculation...
- I've been working with the keyframe API this whole time, but it looks like you can also update the matrix take "snapshots" of the keyframes that way. This still seems like it would require additional keyframes, but it would take care of the translation issue.

Does anyone happen to be familiar with this issue?